# Python - sumif from csv

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, data-analysis

There is a column in my csv called cost, which I want to sum based on another column, called factory, to basically create a breakdown of cost by factory. I have rows such as the following, where there are multiple costs for each factory:

```
Factory,Cost,Cost_Type
Bali,23,0
Sydney,21,1
Sydney,4,2
Denver,8,1
Bali,9,1
```

I'd like to be able to quickly sum the cost per factory, and save these values to a variable. I think one way to do this is by looping through a list of factories, which then loops through the csv. Here is where I've got to:

```
factories= ['Bali', 'Sydney', 'Denver']
totalcost = 0
balicost = 0
sydneycost = 0
denvercost = 0

for factory in factories:
    for row in csv.reader(costcsv):
        if row[0] == factory:
```

Where I'm stuck is that I don't know how to change the variable which is being added to for the different factories, balicost, sydneycost and denvercost. The simplified version, where I'm just getting the total of the cost column was as follows:

```
for row in csv.reader(costcsv):
        totalcost += float(row[1])
```

I'm more than open to different approaches than this (I believe dictionaries could come into it), and appreciate any points in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Community wiki, because it's a little tangential.]

When you're processing tabular data in Python, you should consider the [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) library.  The operation you want to perform is a groupby sum, and that's easily done in two lines:

```
df = pd.read_csv("factories.csv")
by_factory = df.groupby("Factory")["Cost"].sum()
```

which produces a `Series` object you can index into like a dictionary:

```
>>> by_factory
Factory
Bali       32
Denver      8
Sydney     25
Name: Cost, dtype: int64
>>> by_factory["Bali"]
32
```

---

Update, using the updated data-- if you also want to handle `Cost_Type`, you have several options.  One is to select only the rows with Cost_Type == 1:

```
>>> df[df.Cost_Type == 1]
  Factory  Cost  Cost_Type
1  Sydney    21          1
3  Denver     8          1
4    Bali     9          1

[3 rows x 3 columns]
>>> df[df.Cost_Type == 1].groupby("Factory")["Cost"].sum()
Factory
Bali        9
Denver      8
Sydney     21
Name: Cost, dtype: int64
```

or you can expand the groupby and group on both `Factory` and `Cost_Type` simultaneously:

```
>>> df.groupby(["Cost_Type", "Factory"])["Cost"].sum()
Cost_Type  Factory
0          Bali       23
1          Bali        9
           Denver      8
           Sydney     21
2          Sydney      4
Name: Cost, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you DSM, this looks to be a very quick way to get these numbers. There is one extension that would make this the ideal solution. I have a third column in this dataset called "Cost Type" (added to q), and only want to sum the items which have a specific value in this column, in this case, the value is 1. Is there some way to build this filtering into the pandas series?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a dictionary to hold the count for each factories:

```
factoriescost = {}
for row in cvs.reader(costcsv):
    factory = row[0]
    if factory not in ('Bali', 'Sydney', 'Denver'):
        continue
    factorycost = factoriescost.get(factory, 0)
    factoriescost[factory] = factorycost + float(row[1])
totalcost = sum(factoriescost.itervalues())
```

Then you can use `factoriescost` to get the total for a given factory:

```
>>> print totalcost, factoriescost
65.0 {'Denver': 8.0, 'Sydney': 25.0, 'Bali': 32.0}
>>> print factoriescost['Bali']
32.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary as shown below. The code uses a `try` loop to sum the cost of the factories in the dictionary, if the factory is not already inside the dictionary then a `KeyError` will be thrown and so the factory is simply added.

```
a = [['Bali', 23],
     ['Sydney', 21],
     ['Sydney', 4],
     ['Denver', 8],
     ['Bali', 9]]

factories = dict()

for factory, cost in a:
    try:
        factories[factory] += cost
    except KeyError:
        factories[factory] = cost

print(factories)
# {'Denver': 8, 'Sydney': 25, 'Bali': 32}
```

In your example case you would replace the `for` loop with an appropriate one for `csv.reader()` along the lines of:

```
for factory, cost in csv.reader(costcsv):
    try:
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having separate variables, consider a dictionary or, easier, [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

costs = defaultdict(float)

for line in csv.reader(costcsv):
    if len(line) == 2:
        factory, costs = line
        costs[factory] += float(cost)
```

This will give you an output where you can select *any* factory (not just the three you currently hard-code) and get the total cost

```
cost["denver"] == 8.0
```

Comment: Thank you Jon, I particularly like that this will allow more factories, as in reality there are more than 3 that need to be assessed.

Comment: (Whoops, no enter in comments) Thank you Jon, I particularly like that this will allow more factories, as in reality there are more than 3 that need to be assessed. Unfortunately I am now getting an error that reads "ValueError: too many values to unpack", which I think could be due to empty files in the input file, or the other columns in the csv. Any idea of a way around this?

Comment: I have added a fix for this - any line of unexpected length will be skipped

Answer (score 0):

Your csv should be:

```
Factory,Cost
Bali,23
Sydney,21
Sydney,4
Denver,8
Bali,9
```

And in python you can:

```
import csv

factories= ['Bali', 'Sydney', 'Denver']
totalcost = 0

sums = {}

with open('file.csv', 'rb') as f:
    f.next()                        # Jump to second row -> first : header
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] not in sums:
            sums[row[0]] = int(row[1])
        else:
            sums[row[0]] += int(row[1])


for key,value in sums.items():
    totalcost = totalcost  + int(value)
```

The result look like:

```
print sums
>{'Denver': 8, 'Sydney': 25, 'Bali': 32}
print totalcost
>65
```